# Set environment variable not reflected in process.env

Tags: node.js, windows, environment-variables

I have the following code

`console.log(process.env.VAR_X)` in `app.js`
When I run `node app`, it gives me undefined.

I run this on VS Code powershell on Windows 11.
I have also set the environment variable beforehand with `setx VAR_X "abc"`

Also, I am unable to see the set environment variable with `Get-ChildItem Env:` when run on an Admin Powershell outside VS Code.
I have tried closing powershells in VS Code and opening new ones and still cannot retrieve the env variable set.

It seems the `process.env` in Node isn't retrieving the same set of environment variables as the ones I set on Powershell/Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable set using 'setx' are scoped for the current user session so they might not always be available on other terminal windows. Try to set the variable and output on the same session on same terminal window.

Comment: When I simply use `set`, I can see the value immediately in the same session. But when I use `setx`, I cannot even see the value back on the same terminal. 

Anyways, I would want to use the same global env variable even if I close my VS Code or terminals and reopen, even if I log out and in, even if I use another account on the same device. 

I tried the [environment]set...(..., 'machine') too but it doesn't work as desired either. I also tried using the control panel system environment variable setting but it also isn't retrieved in nodeJs or terminals.